# Different execution of the same query for Inline query and a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to cross join a table with itself.

```
select u1.userid,u2.userid from users as u1 join users as u2
```

When I'm writing this query as in line query it gets executed in `0.183 sec`.

But when I'm putting the same query in a routine that I want to use for further processing it takes too much time `(approx 500-600 seconds)`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=root`@`localhost PROCEDURE Test_Cross_Join()  
BEGIN
select u1.userid,u2.userid from users as u1 join users as u2;  
END
```

For the matter of fact it actually get executed only once and from that I was able to get the approximate time duration. But for most of the time when I tried to call that procedure my `"MySQL Workbench"` did not respond and shut off forcefully.  The user table contains `16000 rows`.  When I searched for the execution time of in line query and execution time of I did not get any satisfactory answers, because most of the answers are saying that there should be no time difference. I want to know why there is so much time difference in the execution of same query without any single change of the code.  I am using mysql version 5.7.16 on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.Actually the problem was that during the inline query execution the rows were limited to 50000 so it showed all the rows very easily ,but the routine(stored procedure) was actually trying to return all the (16,000*16,000) rows which MySQL workbench could not display.So during the execution of stored procedure the fetch duration was too long.That's why it forcefully closed.
Sorry for posting wrong question and sorry if I misguided any of you by posting this question. Anyway Thanks guys.